# Why does "101is5".to_i returns 101 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, casting, integer

I opened my loved irb console (Ruby 1.9.3) and I type this:

```
"101is5".to_i
```

And I get:

```
101
```

I am assuming this is the expected behavior, but I fail to see what would be the benefits of doing this? Why do we want a string with numbers and characters to succeed into the Integer casting?

Comment: Reading is cool: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i

Comment: I have read that. I asked, what would be the benefits of doing that casting? "Real life" examples? Practical implications.

Comment: The "I am assuming this is the expected behavior" in your question suggests that you didn't do that tiny bit of research before asking your question.

Comment: Sorry it made you think that way. Actually I assume that from the book "The Well Grounded Rubyist".

Comment: @Nobita you could have mentioned that you'd RTFM'd in the question to save Mu the effort of providing the RDoc link.

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Obviously I should have thought twice before doing the question, and I am sorry. I have asked to be closed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a question, no need to close it IMO. Ruby borrowed a lot from Perl, so I guess this is just another of the Perlisms: http://ideone.com/gFb1d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get an error use `Integer("101is5")` instead

Answer (score 1):

One happy effect of this behaviour is that you don't have to chomp the EOLs from strings or files which are lists of numbers.